# Not Able to Save Data Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

i am trying to save data into hibernate but not able to save because of the error:

> 12:39:24,006 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]
>   (default task-4) Unknown column 'department_id' in 'field list'

Please find the problem statement below:

This is my entity class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Where(clause = "isDeleted = false")
public class Employee extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToOne
    private Department department;

    private int status;

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


}
```

Employee Table:

id | department | status

I am inserting data like this:

```
 @Inject
    CrudService<Employee> employeeManager;

    Department department = new Department();

    // create department and after creating depaerment

    department.setDepartment(department);
    department.setStatus(1);
    department.setId(null);

    employeeManager.create(department);
```

i am getting the error while persisting the data:

```
insert into employee (isdeleted, last_modification, department_id, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

> here i can see that my Employee Table conatins department column but
>   hibernate is generating department_id

internally to insert the records.

Can anybody help me? Please revert if you need any more information.

Comment: *because of the error*: **which** error?

Comment: @JBNizet 12:39:24,006 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) Unknown column 'department_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Well the One to One relationship joins by ID so the default value of the column adds _id. Try to mark it with @Column(name="department")

Comment: Whats in the Department class? Can you post the department class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I guess many employees belong to the same department, so it should be a ManyToOne. Second, you can use JoinColumn to specify the name of the ... join column:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "department")
private Department department;
```

But I'd rather change the name of the column in the database, as `department_id` makes it clearer that the column contains the ID of a department and is thus a foreign key.

Comment: sorry i am new in hibernate and i might be wrong but I want to achive OneToOne mapping . By giving ManyToOne will it not do the same thing ?

Comment: How many employees are there in a department? At most one, or several ones. In the first case, it's a OneToOne. In the second case, it's a ManyToOne. I've never seen any company where each department could only have one person, so I assume it's the second case.

Comment: yes you are right. But, my reuquirement is OneToOne only.

Comment: No, it's not. Since you're being required to model the association between employees and their department, you're being required to use a ManyToOne. Not a OneToOne.